# Adding DateTime as a NEW column on my database

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010

**I'm getting syntax error on the part of ALTER TABLE etc. please help thanks in advance :) Visual Basic**

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=D:\Users\Ashe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\Guidance System.accdb")
    Dim mydate As DateTime
    mydate = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value

   Dim AddCol = "ALTER TABLE Attendance " & _
          "ADD '" & mydate & "');"

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(AddCol, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

Comment: you haven't closed the string in `AddCol`

Comment: Other than the syntax error: you're using a date/time value as your column name. A correct approach would be to: 1) Add the column to the table once; and 2) Use an update statement to set the value for that column for a given record or set of records.

Comment: i will try that solution thanks :)

Comment: I can agree with @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed a string

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        cnn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Users\Ashe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\Guidance System.accdb")
 Dim mydate As DateTime
 mydate = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value

 Dim AddCol = "ALTER TABLE Attendance " & _
              "ADD '" & mydate & "' varchar(100);"

 Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(AddCol, cnn)
            cnn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
```

*Note*: Added `varchar(100)` after the last comment was posted to have a working code here too.

Comment: which line produces the error exactly? "Dim AddCol..." or "Using cmd = ..."

Comment: the queries of the "Dim Add Col.."

Comment: on the ALTER TABLE statement

Comment: you didn't specifiy the datatype of the column. `ALTER TABLE Employees ADD COLUMN Notes TEXT(25)` and as @robby said. create a single column and use `mydate` as values

Answer (score 0):

**I come up with this code and it's now working. thanks y'all! :)**

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Users\Ashe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\Guidance System.accdb")
    Dim mydate As DateTime
    mydate = DateTimePicker1.Value
    mydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Dim AddCol = "ALTER TABLE Attendance " & _
           "ADD '" & mydate & "' varchar(100);"

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(AddCol, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```